# unexpected token `(' defining a function to replace an alias in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create function as an alias which synchronizes files with my server. But I get this error

```
-bash: /home/kenan/.aliases: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/kenan/.aliases: line 2: `rsnos () {'
```

my code is;

```
#!/bin/bash
rsnos () {
    local dest_server="dsp"
    local source_path="/home/kenan/django/event_project/"
    local dest_path="${dest_server}:/home/kenan/www"
    local exclude_all="--exclude={'.git','env','secrets.json','.vscode','static','event_project/wsgi.py','manage.py'}"
    local exc_gev="--exclude={'.git','env','.vscode'}"
    local exc_gevs="--exclude={'.git','env','.vscode','static'}"
    local log_rsync="--log-file /home/kenan/rsync.log"

    rsync -e \"ssh\" -a ${exclude_all} ${source_path} ${dest_path} ${log_rsync} --stats
}
```

If this isn't the proper way to do what I am doing, can you suggest a better way? 
Thanks

Comment: the snippet puts your function name on line 2, but your message is complaining about line 17.  I am guessing that something prior in `.aliases` is causing this issue.

Comment: @DanielFarrell yes, I just cut out some useless code, error is in line 2.

Comment: go try the code you pasted and see if it generates that error for you

Comment: yes same error in line 2

Comment: add the full text of the invocation and response into your question.  Make sure its exact

Comment: I have done that already if you would look at it

Comment: you haven't shown your invocation

Comment: what the hell is invocation? all error and code is there!

Comment: The invocation is *how you start the code*.

Comment: BTW, there are other bugs in this code -- it's using literal quotes in places where only syntactic ones are valid, f/e, and it's using brace expansion in ways that won't possibly work. None of that explains the specific bug described, though; I find myself wondering about nonprinting/hidden characters in your file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the explanation, yes I am a beginner in bash scripting, how would you rewrite this code?

Comment: Added an answer demonstrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcing an `unalias` to prevent the immediate error, and then using arrays rather than strings to store argument lists (for the reasons described in detail in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)), we get:

```
unalias rsnos &>/dev/null ||:

rsnos () {
    local dest_server="dsp"
    local source_path="/home/kenan/django/event_project/"
    local dest_path="${dest_server}:/home/kenan/www"
    local -a exclude_all=( --exclude={'.git','env','secrets.json','.vscode','static','event_project/wsgi.py','manage.py'} )
    local -a log_rsync=( --log-file /home/kenan/rsync.log )

    rsync -e "ssh" -a \
      "${exclude_all[@]}" \
      "${log_rsync[@]}" --stats \
      "$source_path" "$dest_path"
}
```

Because the brace expansions are in an unquoted context when done this way, they actually expand to individual argument-list entries (`--exclude=.git`, `--exclude=env`, etc), which can then be stored in and later expanded from an array.

Comment: This explanation and all, you are a hero

Comment: what do I do to exclude all pyc files? I added '*.pyc' after manage.py to the list but it does not work.

Comment: I would expect that to work (as long as you quote the `*` so it's passed as a wildcard, but you're quoting everything else, so I'd expect that to be the case here). When you use `set -x` to enable tracing, what does it show the command expanding to?

Comment: I did this, and it doesn't show anything
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yBcHPbznPF/

Comment: Do the `set -x` before you *run* the function, not before you *define* it.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an alias. I can reproduce the problem with

```
alias rsnos='echo 123'
rsnos () {
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

First remove the `alias` with

```
unalias rsnos
```

When you are upgrading from aliassen to functions (good choice!), change the filename. The `.alias` should be used for `alias` definitions only.

Comment: yes that is great it is working, but it does not exclude folders and files

Comment: it is like it does not recognize exclude_all variable? but no error.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't recognize the exclusions for the reasons I described. Brace expansions are never honored when quoted, and even if they were, you couldn't use them to form a string.

Comment: The construction `{a,b,c}` does not work inside a string. Try `x="exclude {a,b,c}"; echo $x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not reproducible for me:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
rsnos () {
    local dest_server="dsp"
    local source_path="/home/kenan/django/event_project/"
    local dest_path="${dest_server}:/home/kenan/www"
    local exclude_all="--exclude={'.git','env','secrets.json','.vscode','static','event_project/wsgi.py','manage.py'}"
    local exc_gev="--exclude={'.git','env','.vscode'}"
    local exc_gevs="--exclude={'.git','env','.vscode','static'}"
    local log_rsync="--log-file /home/kenan/rsync.log"

    rsync -e \"ssh\" -a ${exclude_all} ${source_path} ${dest_path} ${log_rsync} --stats
}
```

When I run it, first I source the file from my shell, as the file doens't invoke the function itself.  Then I run from my shell.

```
$ . test.sh
$ rsnos
rsync: failed to open log-file /home/kenan/rsync.log: No such file or directory (2)
Ignoring "log file" setting.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname dsp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Obviously I can't actually make the rsync, but I don't get any errors about the fucntion

Comment: is it because you don't have defined "dsp" config in ssh, or don't have folder "kenan"?